# Update Post creation date when updated

Tags: posts

I am wanting to be able to update a Post and have it show up on my home/main feed as if it were just posted.  For example, if I had a Post titled "Roadmap" or "Planned Features", etc... and it was a list, everytime I updated THAT post, it would update it's creation time to make it look like it was just created instead of updated, so that it would show up in my recent posts.

Any ideas on how to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

When you query your posts, then simply `order_by` *not* `post_date`, but `post_modified` or `post_modified_gmt` instead.